# Android - invalidate does not call onDraw SOMETIMES

Tags: android, ondraw

Trying to determine why the onDraw is not getting called always.
I have following code in onTouch event of a custom view class.

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
 <<do something>><
 switch (eventType) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
           <<do something>>
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
           <<do something>>
            Log.d(TAG, "calling invalidate"); 
            invalidate();
            break;
 }
}
```

The logs show the following statement "calling invalidate" but the ondraw is not ALWAYS called after this log statement. It is almost like batching the invalidates and calling the onDraw once every X times.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is what `invalidate()` does; it marks the current state of the `View` as out of date, and schedules a call to `draw()` to be run on the next drawing iteration, which will be at some point after the current events scheduled on the main Thread (e.g. handling user interaction) are completed.

Comment: But the scheduling causes delay in the way the lines are drawn on the screen. I have tried the hardware acceleration setting as well without any success.

Comment: @Lax: There shouldn't be a significant delay unless you're doing a substantial amount of work in the main thread or have a very complex layout. However, if you really need responsiveness, then maybe you should use something like [`GLSurfaceView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html).

Comment: @Lax, what if I call `invalidate` after both a `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP` and if the two events are very "near" ? Are the two invalidate coalesced?

Comment: Yes, only one draw will take place